# Markdown text is not rendering as I expect on Shapelets-Platform

Tags: python, text, widget, markdown, visualization

I am trying to use Shapelets-platform as a dashboard for an HR presentation. I was trying to do an introduction with text, but it is not showing up as I expected. I have been using the same markdown notation as my code, but it shows all the text.
here is my code and a picture

```
from shapelets.apps import DataApp
app = DataApp(name= ""Presentation HR"")

text = app.text("""""" # Human Resources Analytics
in this presentation, we will be analyzing the data of a company to see if we can find any patterns that can help us predict if an employee will leave the company or not.
I want to start by thanking the company for giving us access to their data and for trusting us with it.
Moreover, I want to thank my team for their hard work and dedication to this project.

# Data
The data we have been given is a csv file with 12 columns and 14999 rows.
The columns are:
- satisfaction_level
- last_evaluation
- number_project
- average_montly_hours
- time_spend_company
- Work_accident
- left
- promotion_last_5years
- sales
- salary
- salary_num
- sales_num
"""""")

app.place(text)
app.register()
```

[image: Data_app]

Answer (score 0):

no problem at all, it is a common mistake. In the text function, you need to specify if you want it as a markdown module. Here is a correction and what it can look like:

```
from shapelets.apps import DataApp
app = DataApp(name= ""Presentation HR"")

text = app.text("""""" # Human Resources Analytics
in this presentation we will be analyzing the data of a company to see if we can find any patterns that can help us predict if an employee will leave the company or not.
I want to start by thanking the company for giving us access to their data and for trusting us with it.
Moreover I want to thank my team for their hard work and dedication to this project.

# Data
The data we have been given is a csv file with 12 columns and 14999 rows.
The columns are:
- satisfaction_level
- last_evaluation
- number_project
- average_montly_hours
- time_spend_company
- Work_accident
- left
- promotion_last_5years
- sales
- salary
- salary_num
- sales_num
"""""", markdown=True)

app.place(text)
app.register()
```